# Chemical equation of wood to charcoal pyrolysis

Tags: heat, hydrocarbons, pyrolysis

The equation for the perfect burning of wood is approximately:

$$\ce{C_xH_yO_z + VOCs + O2 -> CO2 + H2O + volatiles + heat}$$

Where $\ce{C_xH_yO_z}$ represents the cellulose and lignin and VOCs are the volatile organic compounds. How would this equation change in an oxygen starved environment aimed at producing charcoal?

Comment: You can as well use CxHyOz as the empirical summary formula for *particular* wood and it's history. It would vary greatly as lignin has less oxygen than polysaccharides and there is variable moisture content.

Comment: Rather for "equation"  for lack of oxygen.

Comment: And we will never know, we can use only some summary placeholders with empirical formulas.

Comment: If it is *"perfect"* burning, there would be no "VOCs are the volatile organic compounds", just CO2 and H2O (discounting any nitrogen or other byproducts, e.g., NOx).

Comment: [Better understanding the pyrolysis reaction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4867)